# posting data from website to MySQL using PHP does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, server-side

I am new on PHP and trying to do get the user agent from the visitor of the website then send this information to the MySQL.

Home.html (this page has a button where the user should click on it to take him to another page where he will see his device information

```html
<div id="TestMe_img">
  <a href="Result.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Test Your Device">
  </a>
</div>
```

Result.php (the result page contain 2 things: 1- php code. 2- html code)
PHP

```
<?php
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $dbname = "user_data";

    $userAgent = $_POST['userAgent'];


    // Create connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($server,$user, $pass, $dbname);

   // Check connection 
   if($conn -> connect_error) {
     die("Conneciton Failed: " . $conn -> connect_error);
   }

   if (empty($userAgent)) {
     echo "User Agent is blank";
     die();
   }


  $sql = "INSERT INTO UserData (UserAgent) VALUES ('$userAgent')";

  if ($conn -> query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Thank you! Hana is stupid";
  }
  else 
      echo "Unfortunately Hana is smart";

  $conn -> close();
  ?>
```

HTML Part

```
<body onload="userAgent();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>user agent</td>
            <td id="userAgent"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function userAgent(){
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    document.getElementById('userAgent').innerHTML = userAgent;
}
```

However, there is a mistake that I can not find because every time I click on the button it takes me to the result.php and show me the code on the browser with no result appear on the database!

Comment: None of this involves phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Standard form submission requires a form Element. Learn AJAX, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is going to be slightly longer, but bear with me.

1st: You will be getting a "User Agent is blank" message, because the user agent is not actually submitted to the PHP page. You need to put an input (hidden or text) into a form, push the data inside and then submit that form. Change your HTML like this, then at least your date will be submitted:

```
<form method="post" action="Result.php">
  <input type="hidden" id="userAgent">
  <input type="submit" value="Test Your Device">
</form>
```

2nd: You don't even need to do that, because the userAgent is available to PHP already, even without submitting it manually. Just use this variable:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

3rd: You should **NEVER** put unsanitized input into an SQL string. This will lead to SQL injections and your server **will** be hacked. 
Instead of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO UserData (UserAgent) VALUES ('$userAgent')";
$conn->query($sql);
```

You have to use a prepared statement (for pretty much any query that accepts variables), so that nobody can manipulate your query. Otherwise if your $userAgent variable contained a single quote, you could break out of your query and the attacker could inject any SQL code he wanted. So do this to fix your security issue:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO UserData (UserAgent) VALUES (?)");
$statement->bind_param('s', $userAgent);
$statement->execute();
```

The 's' parameter is actually one letter per each parameter you want to prepare in the statement. In this case it indicates you want to pass a string. "i" would be an integer, "d" a double, see here for more: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

4th: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with phpMyAdmin, so you should probably change the title.

I hope this helps you get started.